# rapidly create webpage front end

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, clojure, html

Exposition:

I'm familiar with C/C++/Scheme & OpenGL. I have this client/server program written in Clojure that serves as a todo-list/wiki/forum. The server is written in Clojure. The client is written in Clojure and uses SWT.

Question:

I want to rapidly create a web client version of this. What is the best way to do this? (I Don't use anything complicated, like OpenGL rendering in SWT; just standard widget stuff) I just want something accessible via Safari/Firefox -- and no, I don't want to run it as a Java Applet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Web Kit allows writing of Java code (since server is in Clojure) to create AJAX api.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ruby on Rails, allows you to create very basic CRUD applications quickly. Personally I am looking more a Grails a very similiar framework but for a Java platform

Ruby On Rails - http://rubyonrails.org/

Failing either of those PHP is a good alternative and very quick to get started with

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flex/Actionscript is a pretty good approach for applications that require rich user interaction.